# How to sort Groups in listview using CollectionViewSource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, collectionviewsource

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="messages" Source="{Binding src}"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> 
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"/> 
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> 
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <SortDescription PropertyName="Group" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

The code above works alphabetically. but I want to sort groups by the date which is from groupitems.

For example, I have 3 groups.

```
Group A
- Invoice("cd", 06-24-2015)
- Invoice("car", 06-01-2015)

Group B
- Invoice("cd", 04-21-2015)
- Invoice("car", 06-17-2015)

Group C
- Invoice("cd", 07-02-2015)
- Invoice("car", 06-08-2015)
```

A result I hope to... is like this.

```
Group C
- Invoice("cd", 07-02-2015)
- Invoice("car", 06-08-2015)

Group A
- Invoice("cd", 06-24-2015)
- Invoice("car", 06-01-2015)

Group B
- Invoice("cd", 04-21-2015)
- Invoice("car", 06-17-2015)
```

Group order is Group C -> Group A -> Group B.
Because recent dates for each groupitems are comparison target for result.

Recent date for Group C is 07-02-2015.
Recent date for Group A is 06-24-2015.
Recent date for Group B is 06-17-2015.

so the result is C -> A -> B.

How to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.6.2 added [`GroupDescription.SortDescriptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.groupdescription.sortdescriptions), which works in the same way as `CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions`, and [`GroupDescription.CustomSort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.groupdescription.customsort), which allows you to provide an `IComparer` object.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="messages" Source="{Binding src}"> 
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> 
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Group"/> 
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions> 
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <SortDescription PropertyName="Date" Direction="Descending" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Comment: Thank your for reply. Your solution seem to be just for group sorting ... I wanna group sorting based on  item's date property in the groups. But I didn't find solution yet.